# "Trouble Adding User Input: Getting Unexpected Results in Python"

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and trying to write a simple program to calculate the sum of numbers in a list. Here's my code

python1.py

```
num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
num2 = input("Enter another number: ")

sum_result = num1 + num2

print("The sum is: ", sum_result)`
```

Terminal

```
Enter a number: 2
Enter another number: 5
The sum is: 25

...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit console.
```

Comment: `input` returns strings. Convert them to integers first.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to find the sum of two integers and not two numbers in a list.
To find the sum of two integers, you need to convert the user input to int. This is because the input function returns a string by default. You can use this:

```
num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter another number: "))

sum_result = num1 + num2

print("The sum is: ", sum_result)
```

Note: You can also convert to float using `float(input('Enter a number: '))` if you'd prefer that.